# Add reference to .dll located on shared drive

Tags: python, c#, python.net

When referencing `NET` dynamic link library which is located on shared drive with `Python.NET` exception `FileNotFoundException` is raised. Sample code:

```
import sys
import clr

sys.path.append(PATH_TO_SHARED_NETWORK_DRIVE)
clr.AddReference('MY_DLL')
```

After some googling I found that real problem is that `.NET Framework` does not enable CAS policy by default. So to reference dll on shared drive the `loadFromRemoteSources` switch needs to be enabled. Sample code:

```
from clr import System 
from System import Reflection 

Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(FULL_PATH_TO_MY_DLL.dll)
```

Exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly
> from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be
> sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of
> the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load
> may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the
> assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to enable `loadFromRemoteSources` switch from Python.

Comment: I have no experience with Python.NET, but I think I've been able to work around similar errors in other .NET applications by adding the network folder to my "trusted locations". I think one way to do that is to add the network folder path to "Trusted Sites" on the "Security" tab in "Internet Options" control panel applet. At least it solves the problem of Edge refusing to display PDFs from network folders, so maybe it also works with .NET assemblies. A long shot, I know, but might be worth trying...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the only way to set this setting is via app.config with the contents like in that link you provided:

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

First, try to create a python.exe.config file with the above contents in the same folder as python.exe. If that still doesn't help, the usefulness of python.net kinda diminishes, because then you'd have to create an actual .NET library and have it locally that would reference that remote dll and proxy your calls from there. I think this should work, but I haven't tried it.

And are you sure you really need to reference the dll's on the remote host? Maybe you'll be better off redefining the problem?

Comment: This is not the whole truth. Please, check the Remarks section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd409252(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks